# Are entity classes exclusive to one aggregate

Tags: domain-driven-design

After reading Evans and Vernon I still have one fundamental Question.
I'm aware that of course one entity (instance) can only be in one aggregate.
But can an entity class be used in multiple aggregates (classes)?
For clarification, I ask on the class level.
Other formulation: Can two different aggregate root classes (!) aggregate the same entity class? Of course any of the entity instances has to belong to only one instance of one of the two aggregate root classes.
For Value Object classes this seems to be possible. At least I have the impression that a value object class for example for "money" can be used in different aggregate types.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you rightly pointed out, Entity *instances* shouldn't be shared between aggregates, as one aggregate wouldn't be aware of changes to the entity made through another aggregate and couldn't enforce its invariants.

Entity *classes* could theoretically be shared between 2 aggregates, but, by the same reasoning, only if the set of entity instances in an Aggregate is disjoint from the other. This raises questions :

- Why would you want that in the first place ? If there are two big categories of instances of the same class, isn't this a sign that there are two semantically different concepts, which should each have their own class, or at least subclass ?
- How do you prevent an entity instance belonging to one aggregate from being added to the other, at runtime (bug), or at programming time (uneducated developer decision) ?

Value Objects escape these issues because they are usually immutable or treated as such -- you don't modify a VO, you modify its parent Entity so that it points to a whole new VO instance. Also, as Value Objects don't have an identity, it doesn't make much sense to say that the "same" VO is in two aggregates at the same time. You can thus safely reuse a VO type in different aggregate classes.

Comment: It's probably as simple as this... if you find an entity that must be held by more than a single aggregate root (AR), you probably just found that your entity shall actually be an AR ;)

Comment: Definitely, thanks for pointing that out :) Although it could also beneficially be made a Value Object instead on occasion.

Comment: I see your points and agree. There should be at least different subclasses for the different aggregates. I interpret your answer that this would be ok? Perhaps I should rephrase or pose a new question about inheritance of entity classes and aggregate roots. I'm not sure if its good DDD to have an aggregate root base class and entity base class und several child classes for both effectively doing inheritance over whole aggregates.

Comment: As usual, it depends on your domain. However, as @plalx said, 90% of the time or so it means there's a hidden Aggregate Root waiting to be promoted, so I'd rather look that way. Entity subclasses are extremely rare in my experience.

Comment: Entities can't be shared between AR. If you want info in a aggregate X  that is an entity in aggregate Y, use in aggregate X a value object with specific info needed for this aggregate, which in turn come with partial values from entity in aggregate Y.

Comment: @martinezdelariva Note that by extracting values from an aggregate and place them in a VO, you must accept the fact that the data should be treated as stale, unless it is immutable in the source AR (e.g. the id). Sometimes it's the desired behavior (e.g the price of a Product in a LineItem of an Invoice).

Answer (score 0):

I think Udi's blog post here is very relevant - he suggests that entities can not only be part of multiple aggregates but also be an aggregate root themselves. It is a bit of a funny one to get your head around! http://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/

Comment: That's a really interesting post, and a worthwhile idea (where it makes sense). Do beware that Udi is messing with the terminology a bit (a sensitive subject in DDD, haha). Where **aggregate root** normally defines the root entity in a graph of entities, defining the complete unit that we load, store, and operate on, so that we can ensure consistency, Udi is talking about something else, and should arguably have chosen a different term. He is talking about which object is the _subject_ in a given use case, i.e. the object the use case starts with, which produces new objects.